# Embedding Microsoft form in SharePoint page, without redirecting to new tab or showing full form

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, embedded, microsoft-forms

I embedded a Microsoft Form in SharePoint site page for feedback. But it is showing the total form.

My requirement is that, I will keep a button or quick link for the Form and it must pop-up in a dialogue in the same window, without going to new tab or Form page.

Is this possible or any other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to directly response in the SharePoint Online modern page?  You can use a [MS forms web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-microsoft-forms-web-part-d4b4d3ce-7860-41e4-8a98-76380efe7256) to embed the sharing link for Sending and collecting responses.

It works like below:
[image]

Comment: Hello Jerry, as we have SharePoint forms that show in same page dialogue box when we hit "New item", is there any way to replicate same with Microsoft form? Like I will add a button in sharepoint page naming "Feedback". So when user click on that Feedback button, Microsoft form will pop up like a dialogue box in same page without redirecting

Comment: @RajanaDeepak. Then you may need to do some development works with SPFx to create a custom web part .